# Strange situation mod_rewrite and PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I do not understand something ...

I have CMS written by me and have some strange problem about hidden error from "mod_rewrite". In apache2 error.log  "mod_rewrite" giving :

```
File does not exist: /home/path/to/request, referer: http://IP/request?view=1
```

my `$_GET` / `$_POST` request are all empty

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is ok (returns `request?view=1`)

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is also empty

also i install Drupal CMS to test is it problem on web server, but Drupal works just fine... then i copied drupal ".htaccess" file to my CMS in order to fix mod_rewrite preferences. (Drupal do not create apache error like my )
 No luck, i have same problem again.

also tried with all options in .htaccess from Drupal CMS

I try to turn on `RewriteLog` (several attempts) but without result, not a single log file was not created.

Am i something missing or ... just my cms sucks 
and one more thing, my **CMS work just fine** on other webserver with exactly the same files .... ?????

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico 

#tested RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
#tested RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA] 
#tested Options FollowSymLinks 
#tested Options -MultiViews 
#tested RewriteBase /
```

P.S. sorry for my bad English

Comment: Maybe you can post your htaccess rules. Mainly your rewrite rules.

Comment: Did you add the QSA flag to your rewrite, if you want to  pass GET/POST parameters you need that flag, show us your rewrite plz

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] #tested
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA] #tested

Options FollowSymLinks #tested

Options -MultiViews #tested
  RewriteBase / #tested`

Comment: i will add my .htaccsess rewrite  to basic article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution of my problem! 
The answer is very,very,very simple...

In  apache2 configuration (on Ubuntu) I found  the  `<Directory` tag is duplicated by default ...  I just erase  all directories tags and create one basic.

reload apache2 configuration and every thing starts working just fine

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's your whole .htaccess but you need to enable rewrite, here's a rewrite I use and its never failed:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `RewriteRule` passes everything `(.*)` to a route parameter in index.php then my router class handles the controller ect, the QSA flag will also allow me to pass extra GET/POST values to any part of the script.

hope it helps

ps I dont add the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` because I dont allow folder views and I dont serve content from a folder, everything goes through a controller inc (images,css,js), so there is no need for this in most cases. And it also protects the folders like core & template ect ;)

Comment: I want to know how exactly you disallow folder views

Comment: That is this part `Options -Indexes`

Comment: To protect a folder you add a `.htaccess` with one line `deny from all` this will not stop php from accessing it only browsers.